# Como Listar Usuários com Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estou utilizando Visual Studio 2013, estou criando um novo projeto Asp.NET Web Application usando MVC e autenticação por "Conta de Usuário Individual".

Gostaria de saber como listar todos os usuários registrados.

**Models:**

**IdentityModel**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace WebApplication9.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**AccountViewModels**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication9.Models
{
    public class ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManageUserViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você consegue exibir uma lista qualquer com EntityFramework?

Comment: Sim, eu consigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o contexto está mapeado corretamente, o seguinte Controller pode resolver:

```
public class UsuariosController : Controller
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
    public RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager { get; private set; }
    public MyDbContext context { get; private set; }

    public UsuariosController()
    {
        context = new MyDbContext();
        UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
        RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
    }

    public UsuariosController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

O contexto deve ter a seguinte configuração:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
        .ToTable("Users");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .ToTable("Users");
}
```

Verifique se sua solução já utiliza estes pacotes (`packages.config`). Se sim, experimente fechar a *solution* e abrir novamente.

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.0.0-alpha1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.0.0-alpha1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.0.0-alpha1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Exemplo completo:

> https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample

Comment: Cigano, olha o erro retornado:
'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<WebApplication9.Models.ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no extension method 'Users' accepting a first argument of type.

Comment: A única alteração que fiz foi no contexto, o meu é ApplicationDBContext.

Comment: Seu `ApplicationUser` deriva `IdentityUser`? Pode postar o código dos seus `Models` na pergunta?

Comment: A ApplicationUser deriva de IdentityUser. Coloquei o código lá.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Pode ser que falte alguma configuração no seu contexto.

Comment: O erro continua: 
'...UserManager<WebApplication9.Models.ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'Users' and no extension method 'Users' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<WebApplication9.Models.ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Renatto.Machado.DesRenatto\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication9\WebApplication9\Controllers\UsuariosController.cs 36 43 WebApplication9

Comment: Deve ter algo errado na configuração do seu projeto. Aqui repliquei o exemplo e funcionou. Fiz mais uma edição.

Comment: Cigano, o que fiz foi o seguinte: New Project > ASP.NET Web Application > Escolhi o Template MVC > Alterei a Autenticação para Individual User Account > Botão OK.

Por isso acho que não é algo errado com a configuração do projeto.

Comment: Alguma sugestão Cigano?

Comment: Fiz o mesmo e aqui tudo funcionou após a atualização de pacotes. Experimente apertar <kbd>F12</kbd> em `UserManager` para verificar se a referência está correta.

Comment: Fiz o que falou, fui levado para Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll, v2.0.0.0, onde é definido a classe UserManager.

Comment: E não tem uma property chamada `Users` dentro desse `UserManager`?

Comment: Na verdade não. Só tem isso:

`public class UserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser, string> where TUser : class, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<string>
    {        
        public UserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store);
    }`

Comment: O pacote está desatualizado. Experimente atualizar.

Comment: Cigano, eu entrei no menu Tools > Extensions and Update > Update. Todos os pacotes estão atualizados.

Como faço a atualização que você disse, neste caso?

Comment: `View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console`. Digite o comando `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`.

Comment: Problema resolvido!!!

Obrigado Cigano!